# kill processes with pid using pipes and taskkill in windows

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, wmic, taskkill

I am new to batch scripting and trying to search and kill a list of processes and not sure how to proceed further after the second pipe

```
@echo off
wmic process where "Name like 'java%%.exe' " get Processid, Caption, Commandline | find "abc" |
```

Here I am using WMIC to list all the java processes and filtering them using **find** to get the java processes with a specific word in the Commandline, now I need to kill these processes after finding them. Can this be achieved by taskkill or using a for loop after writing this to a file? I do not want to use call Terminate to kill the processes. can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can process with a `for /F` loop the output of `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe` written to handle `STDOUT` of a `cmd.exe` instance started in background to process the command line. Use a batch file with ``for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PROCESS where "Name like 'java.exe'" GET ProcessId^,Caption^,CommandLine ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "abc"`) do echo %%I`` to see which lines to process. Then run in a command prompt window `for /?` and read the output help to get knowledge how `for /F` can be customized with `tokens=` and `delims=`.

Comment: It is perhaps better to let `wmic.exe` filter on the `java.exe` instances containing a specific string like `abc` inside the `CommandLine` value and let `wmic` output just `ProcessId`  with using option `/Format:VALUE` at end of the `wmic.exe` arguments list for easier processing the output with `for /F`. But please note that `wmic.exe` outputs in Unicode using UTF-16 LE + BOM which `for /F` cannot really correct process. `find.exe` could be used to get the process identifiers output in ASCII for easier processing with `for /F`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I came up with this after going through some documentation, will this work??

@echo off
wmic process where "Name like 'java%%.exe' " get Processid,Caption,Commandline

for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic process where "Name like 'java%%.exe' and Commandline like '%%UAT%%' " get Processid^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
echo Killing UAT Process id %%a
TASKKILL /f /pid  %%a
)

Answer (score 1):

This first looks for processes by .exe name and then looks at the command line of those after having learned the process id:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set exe=winver.exe
set findcommand=foo bar

REM start example programs
start "" "%exe%" %findcommand%
start "" "%exe%" %findcommand% baz
ping -n 3 localhost>nul&rem SLEEP

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic process where "Name like '%exe%'" get ProcessID /format:list') do for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%B in ('wmic process where "ProcessID like '%%A'" get commandLine /format:list') do for /F %%D in ("%%~B") do (
    (echo.%%C|find /I "%findcommand%" >nul)&&call taskkill /PID %%A
)
```

I'm sure there are ways to break this if the command line contains something `echo` does not like but such is life with batch files...

Comment: why was `call` needed here before `taskkill /PID %%A`? I was trying to use `taskkill /PID %%A` directly in a batch script but this threw me a weird error.